# Custom admin product listing page keeps on loading

Tags: magento2, product, layout, adminhtml

Trying to design new custom product listing page on admin. I've used default product listing page's data source. When I try to hit custom admin page, data is coming through but spinner keeps.

Couldn't see any browser console error or exception on Magento's log files.

```
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
<argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
    <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">product_listing.product_listing_data_source</item>
        <item name="deps" xsi:type="string">product_listing.product_listing_data_source</item>
    </item>
    <item name="spinner" xsi:type="string">spinner_columns</item>
    <item name="buttons" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="add" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="name" xsi:type="string">add</item>
            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Add New Post</item>
            <item name="class" xsi:type="string">primary</item>
            <item name="url" xsi:type="string">*/*/new</item>
        </item>
    </item>
</argument>
<dataSource name="product_listing_data_source" component="Magento_Ui/js/grid/provider">
    <argument name="dataProvider" xsi:type="configurableObject">
        <argument name="class" xsi:type="string">Magento\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\ProductDataProvider</argument>
        <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">product_listing_data_source</argument>
        <argument name="primaryFieldName" xsi:type="string">entity_id</argument>
        <argument name="requestFieldName" xsi:type="string">id</argument>
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/provider</item>
                <item name="update_url" xsi:type="url" path="mui/index/render"/>
                <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">entity_id</item>
                </item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </argument>
</dataSource>
<listingToolbar name="listing_top">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="sticky" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
        </item>
    </argument>
    <bookmark name="bookmarks"/>
    <columnsControls name="columns_controls"/>
    <exportButton name="export_button"/>
    <filters name="listing_filters" />
    <filterSearch name="fulltext"/>
    <paging name="listing_paging"/>
</listingToolbar>
<columns name="product_columns" class="Magento\Catalog\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns">
    <settings>
        <childDefaults>
            <param name="fieldAction" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">product_listing.product_listing.product_columns.actions</item>
                <item name="target" xsi:type="string">applyAction</item>
                <item name="params" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="0" xsi:type="string">edit</item>
                    <item name="1" xsi:type="string">${ $.$data.rowIndex }</item>
                </item>
            </param>
        </childDefaults>
    </settings>
    <selectionsColumn name="ids" sortOrder="0">
        <settings>
            <indexField>entity_id</indexField>
        </settings>
    </selectionsColumn>
    <column name="entity_id" sortOrder="10">
        <settings>
            <filter>textRange</filter>
            <label translate="true">ID</label>
            <sorting>asc</sorting>
        </settings>
    </column>
    <column name="thumbnail" class="Magento\Catalog\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Thumbnail" component="Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/thumbnail" sortOrder="20">
        <settings>
            <altField>name</altField>
            <hasPreview>1</hasPreview>
            <addField>true</addField>
            <label translate="true">Thumbnail</label>
            <sortable>false</sortable>
        </settings>
    </column>
</columns>
```

[image]

Comment: Did you put di.xml in etc folder of your module, same of catalog di.xml. I think the spinner is loading may be because of datasource is not binding.

Comment: Found the issue kindly check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41604877/magento-2-custom-module-admin-loading-progress-bar-never-disappear/50827353#50827353